# Calling private methods in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two methods like this

```
def process
  @type = params[:type]
  process_cc(@type)
end

private

def process_cc(type)
  @doc = Document.new(:type => type)
  if @doc.save
    redirect_to doc_path(@doc)
  else
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Error"
  end
end
```

i want, that when i call process_cc from process, it creates the Document and redirect to the doc_path afterwards. maybe i'm expecting behaviour, which rails can't handle, but the process method doesn't call the process_cc method and tries to render a template instead...

any advice on this?

thanks!

Comment: Is your problem still there when you remove the `private` keyword? I'm asking because I dont think your problem is related the method being private.

Comment: if your method `process_cc` is not called, maybe it's overriden by another method `process_cc` in a subclass.

Answer (score 43):

`Object#send` gives you access to all methods of a object (even protected and private).

```
obj.send(:method_name [, args...])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call any (not just private) methods like this

```
class SomeClass

  private
  def some_method(arg1)
    puts "hello from private, #{arg1}"
  end
end

c=SomeClass.new

c.method("some_method").call("James Bond")
```

or

```
c.instance_eval {some_method("James Bond")}
```

BTW, in your code, try to use

```
self.process_cc(...)
```

Comment: If you look at the OPs code, this won't actually have an effect. If one method calls a private method within the same class, it doesn't matter if that method is private since there is no explicit receiver. Also, why convert the method to a proc when you can just use `send("some_method")`?

Answer (score 3):

Action Controller has an internal method called `process` that your method is masking. Pick a different name for your action.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
def process_cc(type)
  @doc = Document.new(:type => type)
  if @doc.save
    redirect_to doc_path(@doc)
  else
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Error"
  end
end
```

to:

```
def process_cc(type)
  @doc = Document.new(:type => type)
  if @doc.save
    redirect_to doc_path(@doc) and return
  else
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Error" and return
  end
end
```